# The intersection of prime ideals of $R$ containing $A$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R$ be a ring and let $A$ be an ideal of $R$.

The nilradical of $A$ is the intersection of the prime ideals of $R$ containing $A$.

Since, $A$ is contained in every prime ideal of $R$, does it imply that the intersection of the prime ideals of $R$ containing $A$ is equal to $A$ itself?
If this is true, then it means that $\operatorname{nilrad}(A) = A$.

May you please give me a counterexample to show why this cannot happen?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why is $A$ contained in every prime ideal of $R$?? This is certainly not true in general...

Comment: I don't understand why do you think that $A$ is contained in every prime ideal of $R$.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, I don't know. But this is how I understood the theorem "The nil radical of an ideal A is the intersection of the prime ideals of R containing A". I think of it as an intersection of all the primes of R such that A is included in each of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the *radical* of $A$ that is the intersection of the prime ideals
containing $A$ not the nil-radical. The radical is denoted by $\sqrt A$.
Always $A\subseteq\sqrt A$ but in general equality doesn't hold.

As an example, in $\Bbb Z$, $\sqrt{n\Bbb Z}=m\Bbb Z$
where $m$ is the product of the prime factors of $n$ (but taken
once only).

Answer (score 1):

Consider $A=(0)$ in the ring $R=\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2)$.

Its nilradical is the prime ideal $(x)$ wich is different from $A$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your example, but I have difficulties in understanding it, since I am not very familiar with this ring.

Answer (score 1):

The set $\{a\}$ is contained in each of the sets $\{a,b,c\}$, $\{a,b,d\}$, $\{a,b,e\}$. Does that imply that the intersection of $\{a,b,c\}$, $\{a,b,d\}$, $\{a,b,e\}$ is equal to $\{a\}$?

Comment: Thank you very much! I got really confused while reading it. Of couse not, but {a} is included in the intersection.